# Java parameters, is it possible to allow a list of parameters of unspecified size?

Tags: java, generics

I was dabbling with getting excessive with parameters to give complete type safety in a system where I had a concept of 'parent and children' objects.  I probably won't keep this level of parameterization as it got so ugly to write the parameters.  However I have something conceptually like this:

```
ModelObject<BaseType extends ModelObject<BaseType, ChildType>, ChildType extends ModelObject<ChildType,?>> 
{

 abstract Set<ModelObject<?, BaseType>> getParents();

 //other logic
 }
```

This is the simplified version, The original version specified parent as well as base and child to make things more explicit and got even uglier.

Assuming I did keep all of this the main weakness is that it allows only one type of parent for child and one type of child per parent, sometimes it makes sense for a parent to have two children.  While I have no use for it at all right now, theoretically it could even make sense to have 3+ children.

I could allow two children with an interface  so something like

```
MyObject extends ModelObject<MyObject, ChildA> implements hasChild<childB>
```

but obviously this only works for two children, unless I want to make a bunch of interfaces for "has 2 children, has 3 children" etc etc.

Is there any way I can write a generic abstract class that would allow any number of 'child' parameters to be created somehow, so that I can write child objects that match any of the list of potential 'children'?  I suspect the answer is no, but I am curious.  This whole structure probably not be worked with as too restrictive and a little ugly with all the types floating around; but was dabbling in it for fun to see if it could be done :)

Comment: I am confused, are you trying to substitute objects with classes, and substitute collections with generics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The details of your question are a bit unclear, but to answer your more basic question of "is it possible to allow a list of parameters of unspecified size?", then the simple answer is yes. You can use variable-length argument lists in Java; it's called [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html).

If you have a MyObject interface and MyObject1, MyObject2, etc., classes all implement that interface, then you can do something like this:

```
private List<MyObject> getParents(MyObject... children) {
    List<MyObject> parents = new ArrayList<MyObject>();

    for(MyObject child : children) {
        parents.add(child.getParent());
    }

    return parents;
}
```

...or this (assuming this particular implementation of MyObject stores its children in a List):

```
public List<MyObject> getChildren() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(children);
}

public boolean hasChildren(MyObject... children) {
    return parent.getChildren().containsAll(Arrays.asList(children)); // 
}
```

Comment: Generics and varargs don't mix.

Comment: this isn't really the right answer; as I was asking about generics which doesn't work with vaargs. but I clearly didn't phrase my answer correctly because *everyone* misinturpreted it. So I'm selecting this as the best answer to what everyone though I was asking :)

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a List of children, rather than each one individually. Then it could be an arbitrary amount and you wouldn't need to reimplement each class.  The only reason you'd need to specify each class differently is if each one is fundamentally different.

Answer (score 0):

```
void foo(Integer... x) {
    Integer x1 = x.length > 0 ? x[0] : 0; 
    Integer x2 = x.length > 1 ? x[1] : 0;//x2 is set to the value of the second string that was passed in
    //...
}
```